# Error al cargar WebView =/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so

Tags: android, kotlin, webview-android

Se están provocando errores en varias apps Android al parecer este problema sucede el día de hoy 22 Marzo 2021

> *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.tototita.rangers <<<
>
> backtrace:   #00  pc 00000000038621f0
> /data/app/~~Qq25ordsRSoMvSoV_QF_g==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_438909034-aO6v1fs0CgGsaddpcsZCMg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so
> (offset 0x646000)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer el problema únicamente ocurre en dispositivos Android 10+

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De acuerdo a el error parece indicar que es en un WebView y al revisar una aplicación en la cual se experimenta este problema se cierra precisamente al cargar un anuncio

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adViewKart"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/6xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Este es el código el cual es muy común y no debería causar ningún problema,

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mAdViewKart : AdView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        mAdViewKart = findViewById(R.id.adViewKart)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdViewKart.loadAd(adRequest)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el problema es una actualización del WebView la cual tiene un bug,

https://www.theverge.com/2021/3/22/22345696/google-android-apps-crashing-fix-system-webview

> [Google soluciona el problema que provoca que las aplicaciones de
> Android se bloqueen con las actualizaciones de Chrome y WebView](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=aa75515d184a2423be444d676b7ebf45)
>
> Los bloqueos se deben a un problema con WebView del sistema Android
>
> Algunas aplicaciones fallaban para los usuarios de Android, pero
> Google lo ha solucionado. El problema se debió a un componente del
> sistema llamado Android System WebView que permite que las
> aplicaciones de Android muestren contenido web. Google ahora tiene una
> solución que requiere que los usuarios actualicen WebView del sistema
> Android a la versión 89.0.4389.105 y Google Chrome a la última
> versión. Ambos están disponibles en Google Play.
>
> Los problemas comenzaron el lunes por la tarde y duraron
> aproximadamente siete horas, según el panel de Google Workspace para
> Gmail. La empresa recomendó utilizar la interfaz de escritorio hasta
> que se resolvieran los problemas.
>
> "Somos conscientes de un problema con WebView que hace que algunas
> aplicaciones de Android se bloqueen para algunos usuarios", dijo
> Google en un comunicado a The Verge. "Actualmente estamos trabajando
> para validar completamente el alcance y se está realizando una
> corrección".

Incluso Samsung respondió:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La solución por el momento es desinstalar la actualización del WebView**

Ir a `Configuración` > `Aplicaciones` > tocar los tres puntos en la esquina superior derecha > mostrar aplicaciones del sistema > buscar `"Android System WebView"` > seleccionar `"Desinstalar actualizaciones"`. Al realizar estos pasos se recomienda reiniciar el teléfono.

---

**Actualización:**
Al parecer ya se tiene solución, el comunicado oficial de Google es:

The problem with Gmail has been resolved. We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured that system reliability is a top priority at Google, and we are making continuous improvements to make our systems better.

La actualización del sistema Android WebView y Google Chrome a través de Google Play ahora debería resolver el problema para todos los usuarios.

1. Navega a la aplicación Play Store.
2. Busque WebView del sistema Android
   (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)
3. Seleccione la opción "Actualizar".
4. Repita estos pasos para Google Chrome (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome)

Para obtener más información sobre la actualización de aplicaciones de Android, consulte:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Básicamente, tu problema es que estás llamando a un `banner` con `id` a pero en tu `activity` el `banner` tiene otro `id`. Observa la siguiente línea:

```
android:id="@+id/adViewKart" //Aquí el id es adViewKart
```

Pero, en tu forma de crear la publicidad:

```
mAdViewKart = findViewById(R.id.adView) //pero aquí le dices que se llama adView
```

Solución:

```
mAdViewKart = findViewById(R.id.adViewKart)
```